# Getting a Buildout Cache, so that buildout will work when download.zope.org is down

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

This blog gives a summary of how to use buildout when download.zope.org is down http://devblog.4teamwork.ch/blog/2013/06/06/download-dot-zope-dot-org-is-down-how-to-fix-buildout/ however it is specific to Plone 4.2.

How do I go about getting a similar cache for Plone 4.3.1 so that my buildout won't fail when download.zope.org is down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of this particular outage, you don't need a cache[1]: you need a valid `extends =` target. I've just fixed my Plone 4.3 buildout to avoid download.zope.org[2]. This should work for you:

```
[buildout]
extends = https://raw.github.com/plock/pins/master/plone-4-3

[plone]
#eggs +=
```

[1] Because Plone extends configuration files located on download.zope.org: http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.1/versions.cfg

[2] As soon as a find the appropriate Zope configuration files, I'll fix 4.3.1 too.

Comment: Thanks aclark,
Also Jonas Baumann has alerted me to the fact that he has updated his buildout caches with information for Plone 4.3.1. https://gist.github.com/jone/5720499

Comment: I cant get bootstrap or buildout working today... looks like the same issue as http://download.zope.org/ is not responding... not sure why bootstrap is not working though? Is there a good workaround here? @aclark's github repo doesnt have the files anymore from the looks...

Comment: @AaronWilliams They moved here: https://github.com/plock/pins, I updated my answer.